# Need an iOS library or framework for iPhone to Ruby on Rails API interaction

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ios, ios4

I'm looking into iOS libraries and/or frameworks that I can pull into a current project to interact with a Ruby on Rails API.

I was going to go with ObjectiveResource aka iPhone-On-Rails (http://iphoneonrails.com/) because of its ease of use, but it seems like there hasn't been any development on it since 2009.

Do any of you know of a better alternative to ObjectiveResource? I would like something that is well supported and maintained with good documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, interacting with Rails is simply interacting with a REST API.

That said, here is a very popular asset you should look at: http://restkit.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked out RakeKit and looks like it's almost exactly what I wanted. Then I realized I could just rework my current API implementation on the Rails side to actually utilize Rails native systems instead of using the grape gem mixed in with my Rails app, followed up with ASIHTTPRequest to interact with the API as you normally would. I guess I over-thought this thing from the get go and made it messier than it needed to be. Thanks again!